# HJSON C# library for PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, hjson

I'm trying to use HJSON C# library for PowerShell: https://github.com/hjson/hjson-cs
I've successfully compiled the dll, put it into a folder and added the type via standard procedure:

```
#LOAD
$scriptRoot = Split-Path $script:psEditor.GetEditorContext().CurrentFile.Path

$FilePath = ( Get-Item .\Hjson.dll ).FullName
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$FilePath")

[Hjson.IJsonReader]::new()

[Hjson.hjson]::Load("$scriptRoot\test.hjson")
```

I'm trying to follow examples to get the basics:
Read method: https://github.com/hjson/hjson-cs#read

```
# var jsonObject = HjsonValue.Load(filePath).Qo();

$jsonTempData = [Hjson.HjsonValue]::Load("$scriptRoot\test.hjson")
$jsonObject = [Hjson.JsonUtil]::Qo($jsonTempData)
$jsonObject
```

but the output is missing values:

```
PS D:\OneDrive\PS-HJSON> $jsonObject

Key       Value
---       -----
hello
text
quote
otherwise
abc-123
commas
but
trailing
multiline
number
negative
yes
no
null
array
array2


PS D:\OneDrive\PS-HJSON>
```

So I can't see values. Why it doesn't work like JSON objects?

And when I try to iterate through keys:

```
foreach ( $item in $jsonObject) {
    $item.Key, $item.Value
}
```

I got this:

> The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the
> collection: "The operation is invalid due to the current state of the
> object. "

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I don't know c# enough to know what to do.

Comment: Try chaining your method calls. `$jsonTempData = [Hjson.HjsonValue]::Load("$scriptRoot\test.hjson").Qo()`

Comment: It won't work for Powershell.

Comment: So with the values missing in initial import variable $jsonTempData the problem likely is in the C# or possibly in your Load call but I'd bet on something lower level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is just written in a way that doesn't work great with how PowerShell displays data it doesn't have format information for.

### Why

- `JsonValue` (the type emitted by `Hjson.Load`) is more or less a dictionary of `string` to `JsonPrimitive` (or more `JsonValue` for nesting).
- The reason you don't see any values when you output the variable is because PowerShell by default just converts objects to a string.  The `JsonValue` to string conversion is just an empty string, so it appears like a null value, but it's a full object.
- The reason it throws the `InvalidOperationException` referencing enumeration is because PowerShell tries to enumerate anything that implements `IEnumerable`.  But, `JsonPrimitive` will throw when you try to enumerate it if the real value of the object isn't an array.

### Solution

#### Individual values

If you want to get an individual value, you can call the `JsonPrimitive.ToValue` method.  This will convert the `JsonPrimitive` to the equivalent .NET type.

```
$jsonObject = [Hjson.HjsonValue]::Load("myFile.hjson")
$jsonObject['MyKey'].ToValue()
```

The problem with this is it will only work on keys you know are primitives. That means to do a full conversion to a normal displayable type you would have to enumerate the `JsonValue`, check if it's a `JsonPrimitive` or `JsonObject`, then either call `ToValue` or recurse into the nested object.

#### Full conversion

A simpler approach might be to just convert it to json as PowerShell is a lot better at handling that

```
$jsonObject = [Hjson.HjsonValue]::Load("myFile.hjson")
$stringWriter = [System.IO.StringWriter]::new()
$jsonObject.Save($stringWriter, [Hjson.Stringify]::Plain)
$hjsonAsPSObject = $stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString() | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The `Save` method takes a path, a stream, or a `TextWriter`.  The `StringWriter` object is just an easy way to get a string from something that accepts a `TextWriter`.

### How to tell?

If you're ever faced with an object that you think should have a value but displays like it doesn't have a value, there's a solid chance it just doesn't display right in PowerShell.  In this scenario, the easiest way you could have tested would be trying some of these:

```
# Shows you the objects type, or if it really is $null it will throw
$jsonObject['jsonKey'].GetType()

# This will tell you the properties and methods available on an object
# but in this case it would throw due to the enumeration funk.
$jsonObject['jsonKey'] | Get-Member

# This gets around the enumeration issue.  Because there's no pipeline,
# Get-Member gives you the members for the type before enumeration.
Get-Member -InputObject ($jsonObject['jsonKey'])
```

Comment: Fantastic investigation! Thank you very much! I will just convert HJSON to JSON and save all the trouble. Rewriting c# code to work better/outofthebox with PS is beyound my skils